# PHP: Check is file upload is a valid PDF file

Tags: php, pdf, mime-types

I want to validate if a file submited by the user is a valid PDF file, with PHP. **BUT** i have this limitations:

1. PHP 5.0.4.
2. I can't use **mime_content_type** and **finfo_open**
3. I am having issues with shell_exec (file command). So, again, i cant use it.

The only thing i need to know is if the file is in fact a PDF. ¿What lower-level solution can i use? Like reading the first x chars and look for %PDF or something like that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: PHP 5.0.4 is more than 13 years old, support for the 5.0 branch [ended in 2005 with 5.0.5](http://php.net/eol.php). Hopefully this is not an application on the public internet

Comment: if you can use `fopen` all PDF files start with `%PDF-` like you suggest. Any reason you can't just do that?

Comment: I know  Karsten Koop. Tell my boss that.

Comment: @apokryfos No, i will do it. I was wondering what other options were available.

Answer (score -1):

You're limited, but you can do of things in the backend after form submission using `$_FILES`, which is from a form submitted with input type="file":

```
$_FILES['form_name_for_input_type_equals_file']['name'] ---> check if extension here is .pdf
$_FILES['form_name_for_input_type_equals_file']['type'] ---> check if mime type here is application/pdf
```

For more info about `$_FILES` click [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php).

Comment: Thanks, but i dont trust in those validations. The user can rename a executable file (changing the extension to .pdf) and bypass the validation. Something similar can happen whit the mime type.

Comment: As I said you're limited with what you can do

Answer (score -2):

Try using this

```
$allowed =  array('pdf');
$filename = $_FILES['document_file']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(!in_array($ext,$allowed) ) {
    echo 'Please, only upload PDF files';
}
```

What you could also do is let PHP call up a  BASH script to confirm if it is a pdf by the OS, which I wouldn't advise you to do but it's as low level as it can get. What you could also do is use a regex in either bash or PHP to check the fileheaders if they match with the fileheaders of a PDF.

Answer (score -2):

Try it:
It work for me:

```
$file_type = $_FILES['filename']['type'];
if($file_type=='application/pdf'){
    // is pdf
}else{
   // not pdf
}
```